# Convert list of tuples to dictionary with multiple dict values for a key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My list of tuples:

```
list = [('WALMART', '601 12th Avenue Northeast',916523), 
('WALMART SHARED', '1953 west brown street',916523)]
```

Wanted to Convert the list of tuples to Dictionary as shown below:

```
dict =
    {
        916523: [{
                'cancmpname': 'WALMART',
                'canaddress': '601 12th Avenue Northeast',
            },
            {
                'cancmpname': 'WALMART SHARED',
                'canaddress': '1953 west brown street',

            },
        ]
    }
```

My code so far:

```
dict = {}
for result in list:
      dict[result[2]]={}
      dict[result[2]]['cmpname']=result[0]
      dict[result[2]]['cmpaddress']=result[1]
```

This converts the list into a dictionary with the latest value it doesn't append both the results as dictionary array values

result from my code:

```
dict =
    {
        916523: {
                'cancmpname': 'WALMART SHARED',
                'canaddress': '1953 west brown street',

            }

    }
```

Comment: Use `append()` to append a new dict to a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution which does not use any library, although I think the defaultdict solution is cleanner:

```
li = [('WALMART', '601 12th Avenue Northeast',916523),
('WALMART SHARED', '1953 west brown street',916523)]

d = {}

for name, address, zipcode in li:
    d.setdefault(zipcode, []).append(dict(cancmpname=name, canaddress=address))
```

A few notes

- Do not use `list` and `dict` to name your variables, you effectively overshadow the built-in types
- If a key is not in the dictionary, `setdefault` will create the value (an empty list in this case) and assign to that key
- If a key already exists in the dictionary, `setdefault` will do nothing
- In both cases, `setdefault` will return the value for that key, which I took and append a new dictionary to it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
l = [('WALMART', '601 12th Avenue Northeast',916523), ('WALMART SHARED', '1953 west brown street',916523)]
final_data = {a:[dict(zip(['cancmpname', 'canaddress'], i[:-1])) for i in b] for a, b in itertools.groupby(l, key=lambda x:x[-1])}
```

Output:

```
{916523: [{'canaddress': '601 12th Avenue Northeast',
       'cancmpname': 'WALMART'},
      {'canaddress': '1953 west brown street',
       'cancmpname': 'WALMART SHARED'}]}
```

Comment: It's like reading one-line-command, so elegant and proficient!

Comment: @Xiang Thank you! `itertools` + list comprehension is very powerful.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` for an O(n) solution.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [('WALMART', '601 12th Avenue Northeast',916523), 
       ('WALMART SHARED', '1953 west brown street',916523)]

d = defaultdict(list)

for name, address, code in lst:
    d[code].append({'cancmpname': name, 'canaddress': address})
```

**Result**

```
defaultdict(list,
            {916523: [{'canaddress': '601 12th Avenue Northeast',
                       'cancmpname': 'WALMART'},
                      {'canaddress': '1953 west brown street',
                       'cancmpname': 'WALMART SHARED'}]})
```

**Explanation**

- Do *not* name variables after classes, e.g. use `lst` instead of `list`, `d` instead of `dict`.
- For each item in `lst`, build a dictionary and append it with key equal to the code.

**Benchmarking**

```
lst = [('WALMART', '601 12th Avenue Northeast',916523), 
       ('WALMART SHARED', '1953 west brown street',916523)]

def jpp(lst):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for name, address, code in lst:
        d[code].append({'cancmpname': name, 'canaddress': address})
    return d

def ajax(l):
    return {a:[dict(zip(['cancmpname', 'canaddress'], i[:-1])) for i in b] for a, b in itertools.groupby(l, key=lambda x:x[-1])}

lst = lst*1000

%timeit jpp(lst)    # 696 µs per loop
%timeit ajax(lst)   # 3.68 ms per loop
```